# Excel 2010 - Format Code to Remove Percentage Sign Without Changing the Value

Tags: excel, charts, format, hide, percentage

I'm looking for an Excel format code that would hide the percentage sign on the y-axis of a "100% Stacked Column" chart. 
I don't want to change the data, but instead of seeing:

100%, 80%, 60%, 40%, 20%, 0%, -20%

I'd like to see:

100, 80, 60, 40, 20, 0, (20)

I used a fairly uncomplicated format code at my last job, but have forgotten what it was.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a column of values like:

[image]

Running this little macro will apply a Custom Format to each cell selected:

```
Sub ApplyCustomFormats()
    Dim DQ As String, msg As String
    Dim r As Range, t As String

    DQ = Chr(34)

    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        If Left(t, 1) = "-" Then
            t = "(" & Mid(t, 2)
            t = Left(t, Len(t) - 1) & ")%"
        End If
        msg = DQ & Left(t, Len(t) - 1) & DQ
        r.NumberFormat = msg & ";" & msg & ";" & msg & ";"
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

***NOTE:***

The values are not changed, only the display formats.
Because these are Custom Formats, only a limited number of cells can be formatted like this.